# Understanding openzeppelin's crowdsale contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I am new to solidity and am trying to understand this openzeppelin [crowdsale contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol).

I am currently stuck on the `_deliverTokens` function and unable to understand how this function works. As far as I understood, the `token` here is actually referring to the ERC20 token but when it calls `token. transfer()`, whose tokens its transferring? Does this mean that the crowdsale contract's address owns the tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in this implementation `Crowdsale` contract's address owns the tokens to make `transfer` function workable.

If you want to hold tokens on some separate address (token holder address) you should approve some tokens amount to `Crowdsale` contract and use `transferFrom` method to transfer tokens from holder address to the investor's address.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the detail of transfer function in below link.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/BasicToken.sol

```
 /**
  * @dev transfer token for a specified address
  * @param _to The address to transfer to.
  * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
  */
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);

    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
 }
```

So the token of user who calls this function (msg.sender) will be transferring.